# How do I tell my AWS Ubuntu instances to pull from codecommit?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codecommit

how can i pull my repository from codecommit on an instance from AWS with Ubunutu?

I installed awscli and evrytime when i try pull with the command:

```
aws codecommit operation/get-repository
```

The System says: this is not a valid command.

And at the command list, there is also no operation named "codecommit"

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may need to update your version of AWSCLI. It may pre-date the `codecommit` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS CodeCommit Command Line Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cmd-ref.html)

> **Note**
>
> AWS CodeCommit works only with AWS CLI versions **1.7.38 and later**. To determine which version of the AWS CLI you have installed,
> run the aws **--version** command.
>
> To upgrade an older version of the AWS
> CLI to the latest version, uninstall the older version by following
> the instructions in Uninstalling the AWS CLI, and then install the
> latest version by following the instructions in Installing the AWS
> Command Line Interface.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you!